# BASH Script to iterate through a list of IDs in an XML file and print/output the name to shell or output file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, grep

I'm looking to iterate through a list of ID numbers which matches ID numbers in an XML file and print the line below using BASH (and AWK) to the shell or redirect it to a third, output file (output.txt)

Here is the breakdown:

ID_list.txt (shortened for this example - it has 100 IDs)

```
4414
4561
2132
999
1231
34
489
3213
7941
```

XML_example.txt (thousands of entries)

```
<book>
  <ID>4414</ID>
  <name>Name of first book</name>
</book>
<book>
  <ID>4561</ID>
  <name>Name of second book</name>
</book>
```

I'd like the output of the script to be the names of the 100 IDs from the first file:

```
Name of first book
Name of second book
etc
```

I believe it's possible to do this using BASH and AWK with a for loop (for each in file 1, find the corresponding name in file2). I think you can recurisvely GREP for the ID number and then print the line below it using AWK. Even if the output looked like this, I can remove the XML tags after:

```
<name>Name of first book</name>
<name>Name of second book</name>
```

It's on a Linux server but I can port it over to PowerShell on Windows. I think BASH/GREP and AWK are the way to go.

Can someone help me script this?

Comment: Show us what you tried and what specifically you're having problems with - otherwise it looks like you want us to write it for you.

Comment: Shell and/or `awk` is not the right choice for parsing XML.

Comment: @user2062950, you are right, apologies for not posting my version prior to asking. I was using while read; do and a for i in ID_list.txt solution, but Dogbane's solution(s) below were cleaner.

Comment: It really isn't that terrible using `BASH_REMATCH`, though still obviously simpler in a language that includes a package to do it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
while IFS= read -r id
do
    grep -A1 "<ID>$id</ID>" XML_example.txt | grep "<name>"
done < ID_list.txt
```

Here's another way (one-liner). This is more efficient because it uses a single grep to extract all the ids instead of looping:

```
egrep -A1 $(sed -e 's/^/<ID>/g' -e 's/$/<\/ID>/g' ID_list.txt | sed -e :a -e '$!N;s/\n/|/;ta' ) XML_example.txt | grep "<name>"
```

Output:

```
<name>Name of first book</name>
<name>Name of second book</name>
```

Comment: Thank you, @dogbane. Both of these worked as expected. I find the first one easier to read but both did exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Every response on this platform should be like this one.

Answer (score 3):

Given an ID, you can get the name using XPath xpressions and the `xmllint` command, like this:

```
id=4414
name=$(xmllint --xpath "string(//book[ID[text()='$id']]/name)" books.xml)
```

So with this, you could write something like:

```
while read id; do
    name=$(xmllint --xpath "string(//book[ID[text()='$id']]/name)" books.xml)
    echo "$name"
done < id_list.txt
```

Unlike solutions involving `awk`, `grep`, and friends, this is using
an actual XML parsing tool.  This means that while most other
solutions might break if they encountered:

```
<book><ID>4561</ID><name>Name of second book</name></book>
```

...this would work just fine.

`xmllint` is part of the `libxml2` package, and is available on most
distributions.

Note also that recent versions of awk have [native XML parsing](http://blog.oddbit.com/2012/09/10/awk-parsing-xml/).

Comment: What is book.xml?

Comment: A file containing the sample XML data from the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR{ ids["<ID>" $0 "</ID>"]; next }
found { gsub(/^.*<name>|<[/]name>.*$/,""); print; found=0 }
$1 in ids { found=1 }
' ID_list.txt XML_example.txt
Name of first book
Name of second book
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go the `BASH_REMATCH` route if I had to do it in bash

```
 BASH_REMATCH
          An  array  variable  whose members are assigned by the =~ binary
          operator to the [[ conditional command.  The element with  index
          0  is  the  portion  of  the  string matching the entire regular
          expression.  The element with index n  is  the  portion  of  the
          string matching the nth parenthesized subexpression.  This vari‐
          able is read-only.
```

So something like below

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line; do
  [[ $print ]] && [[ $line =~ "<name>"(.*)"</name>" ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"

  if [[ $line == "<ID>"*"</ID>" ]]; then
    print=:
  else
    print=
  fi
done < "ID_list.txt"
```

Example output

```
> abovescript
Name of first book
Name of second book
```